# How can I display the clicked products by user on a list in another view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm

I am using MVC3 Viewmodel pattern with Entity Framework on my webbapplication.

My Index View is list of products with image, price and description and etc.

Products with the information I mentioned above is in div boxes with a button that says "buy".

[image: divbox]

I will be working with 2 views one that is the Index View that will display all the products and the other view that will display the products that got clicked by the buy button.

What I am trying to achieve is when a user click on buy button the products should get stored in the other view that is cart view and be displayed.

I have problems on how to begin the coding for that part.

The index View with products is done and now its the buy button function left to do but I have no idea how to start.

This is my IndexController:

```
private readonly HomeRepository repository = new HomeRepository();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Productlist = repository.GetAllProducts();

    var model = new HomeIndexViewModel()
    {
        Productlist = new List<ProductsViewModel>()
    };

    foreach (var Product in Productlist)
    {
        FillProductToModel(model, Product);
    }

    return View(model);

}

private void FillProductToModel(HomeIndexViewModel model, ProductImages productimage)
{
    var productViewModel = new ProductsViewModel
    {

        Description = productimage.Products.Description,
        ProductId = productimage.Products.Id,
        price = productimage.Products.Price,
        Name = productimage.Products.Name,
        Image = productimage.ImageUrl,
    };
    model.Productlist.Add(productViewModel);
}
```

In my ActionResult Index I am using my repository to get the products and then I am binding the data from the products to my ViewModel so I can use the ViewModel inside my view. Thats how I am displaying all the products in my View.

This is my Index View:

```
    @model Avan.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel

         @foreach (var item in Model.Productlist)
                    {
                     <div id="productholder@(item.ProductId)" class="productholder">  
                     <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" alt="" />
                     <div class="productinfo">
                     <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h2> 
                     <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>    
                     @Html.Hidden("ProductId", item.ProductId, new { @id = "ProductId" }) 
</div>
                     <div class="productprice">     
                     <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)</h2>
                     <input type="button" value="Läs mer" class="button" id="button@(item.ProductId)">  
                     @Html.ActionLink("x", "Cart", new { id = item.ProductId })  // <- temp its going to be a button                   
                    </div>                                   
                    </div>

             }
```

Since I can get the product ID per product I can use the ID in my controller to get the data from the database. But I still I have no idea how I can do that so when somebody click on the buy button I store the ID where? and how do I use it so I can achieve what I want to do?

Right now I have been trying to do following thing in my IndexController:

```
public ActionResult cart(int id)
        {
            var SelectedProducts = repository.GetProductByID(id);


            return View();
        }
```

What I did here is that I get the product by the id. So when someone press on the temp "x" Actionlink I will recieve the product. All I know is that something like that is needed to achieve what im trying to do but after that I have no idea what to do and in what kind of structure I should do it.

Any kind of help is appreciated alot!

**Short Scenario:**

looking at the Index I see 5 products, I choose to buy 3 products so I click on three "Buy" buttons. Now I click on the "Cart" that is located on the nav menu. New View pops up and I see the three products that I clicked to buy.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do ajax with some client side updating of a Div.

Comment: Are you sure? Beacuse when I click on actionLink that is instead of the button right now that is inside my view. I can get the product by the ID. I need to somehow store it in another other view

Comment: Feels like there are only two ways to do that.  Share the same instance of the viewmodel between the two components, or write to the db what gets put into the cart and have the cart get the data.

Comment: You should look into standard web state management, a common method for this type of scenario is to use cookies to store the products a user looked at, otherwise use some form of session state to manage the users products. This could be a custom implementation that you store in a database, cookies, session, etc.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter I was thinkin in that direction to use the same Viewmodel in both views, but the part of storing the product id to the other controller or view is hard for me to understand I guess that would be a great solution to this. I dont know if I should work in one controller or two? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ajax to add it to a cart on a separate action like so:

Action would look something like this:

```
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int productID)
    {
        List<int> cart = (List<int>)Session["cart"];
        if (cart == null){
           cart = new List<int>();
        }
        cart.Add(productID);

        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Status = "Success" } };
    }
```

Your Javascript would look something like this:

```
$(function(){ // after page load

    $(".button").live("click", function(){ // add a listener to the buttons
        var $this = $(this), // record which button has been pressed
            productID= $this.data('productID'); // Get the product ID from the button

        $.ajax({ // initiate a ajax request
                url: '/controller/AddToCart', // to this address
                type: "post", // of type post
                cache: false, // don't cache any results
                data: {id: productID}, // post the product id
                success: function (data) { // on success
                   data = eval(data); // get the data if you want it
                   $this.addClass('productSelected'); // add a class that shows that the button was updated
                },
                error: function (result) { // on error
                    $(".validation-summary-errors").append("<li>Error connecting to server.</li>"); // this tells the world that there was an error in the ajax request
                }
            });
    }
});
```

One tiny bit you will need to add to your view is:

```
<input type="button" value="Läs mer" class="button" id="button@(item.ProductId)" data-productID='@item.ProductId' />
```

If you are not familiar with JQuery I recommend taking a few seconds to check it out as it will greatly advance your MVC experience. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Could you explain your javascript please

Comment: I edited the answer with comments to give a better explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! just a question do I need create a view for AddToCart action?

Comment: I ama also getting this error: 

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddToCart(Int32)' in 'AvanShop.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameternamn: parameters

Comment: The attribute data-productID will store the id of the item you wish to update. $(this).data('productID') grabs the information from the data attribute.  See the last code sample with the <input type="button ...

Comment: the error I mentioned before turns up everytime I click on the button, strange part is when i debug with chrome the click event doesnt trigger but the error pops up everytime I click on the button

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry change this line: 'data: {id: productID},' to 'data: {productID: productID},'

Comment: Now it works! :) Now my actionresult AddToCart is triggered, but I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object, at this line: "cart.Add(productID);". Whats the next step that I should do ?

Comment: Awesome! Now the ID gets stored! :) What should I do now with this action? In some way I need to display this products in another view. I dont need any code I just need to know what my next steps are :)

Comment: Add another view/action (ie GetShoppingCart) which returns a partial view of all the items in the Session["cart"].

Comment: I will do my best :) If I get stuck I can link you the new question, Thanks alot for everything!

Comment: The action GetShoppingCart should it have any paremeter?

Comment: I have a new question up could you check it out kerMingle please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18829/discussion-between-kermingle-and-avar)